# How to update a FloatField: Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to update  field in my models with the newly calculated value from my view and when I try to update my field using `total.objects.update(total=total)` this is what i get `'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'objects'`.

I also have some other questions, I'm currently calculating the total field from initial values inputted when the item is created, using  the save() method.  is this a good idea ? or is there a better way of doing this? the reason I'm currently doing this is because i display the a list of items with their initial values.

Over all I'm trying to make a tools inventory system. I also have some other concerns.

How can I use this view  on multiple items types? the model items is an abstract model that contains all common fields,and every tool type inherits this model and will be using the same operations, calculate the new cantidad_existente and update the total  fields. Is there a better way?

my views.py

```
def calcular_nueva_cantidad(ce, up):
    total = ce + up
    return total

class updateForm(forms.Form):
    update = forms.IntegerField()

def actualizar_cantidad(request, pk):
    # trae de la base de datos el valor de la cantidad existente 
    cantidad_existente = Cortadores.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('cantidad_existente')
    c = cantidad_existente.values_list('cantidad_existente', flat=True)
    ce= c[0]
    # trae de la base de datos el valor de precio_unitario
    precio_unitario = Cortadores.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('precio_unitario')
    p = precio_unitario.values_list('precio_unitario', flat=True)
    pu =p[0]
    # trae de la base de datos el valor de la total 
    total = Cortadores.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('total')
    print(F'el precio unitario es {total} ----------------------------------------------------')

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = updateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            up =  form.cleaned_data['update']

            nce = calcular_nueva_cantidad(up, ce)

            total = nce * pu
            print(F' el nuevo total es {total} -----------------------')
            # nce.save()
            cantidad_existente.update(cantidad_existente=nce)
            total.objects.update(total=total)




            return render(request, 'inventario/cortadores.html', {'nce':nce})
        else:
            # Redirect to fail page after POST
            return HttpResponse('')

    else:
        form = updateForm()

    return render(request, 'inventario/update-cortador.html', {'form':form, 'cantidad_existente':cantidad_existente })
```

my models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30,)
    numero_parte = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad_existente = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    update = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    cantidad_minima = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    precio_unitario = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    asignado_a = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    anaquel = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ANAQUEL, blank=True, null=True)
    posicion_en_x = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    posicion_en_y = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True



    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.total = self.cantidad_existente * self.precio_unitario
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)



class Cortadores(Item):
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipos_Cortadores,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Materiales, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    filos = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=GABILANES)
    diametro = models.ForeignKey(Diametros, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    longitud = models.ForeignKey(Longitud, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desbaste = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DESBASTE)




    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cortadores"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventario:cortadores-list', kwargs={'id': self.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (  str(self.tipo), str(self.material), str(self.filos), str(self.diametro), 
                                        self.longitud, self.desbaste
                                        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you have two variables called `total`. Just rename one of them.

```
total = Cortadores.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('total')
...
new_value = nce * pu
total.objects.update(total=new_value)
```

Comment: Thanks, regarding my second question -How can I use this view on multiple items types? -   is there  guide or example you can provide me? how can i search for this ( I cant find words to correctly describe what i want to do)

Answer (score -1):

There is a error, you changing you queryset to flaot value, and then trying to use queryset functions on it, so you should use other variable in total and not your own queryset

```
total = Cortadores.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('total')
total = nce * pu // This line replace your queryset to float
total.objects.update(total=total)
```

You should use something like that

```
qs_total = Cortadores.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('total')
total = calcular_nuevo_total(nce, pu)
for value in qs_total:
    value.total=total
    value.save()
```

To use it as generic like you want use pass the class reference as parameter and use it to call your query set

```
def something(__class__):
    class.objects.all()
```

**EDIT: Making a generic method to use with any class**

```
from .models import Cortadores, OtherModelExample

def generic_update_noreturn(__class__, pk, total)
    qs= __class__.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('total')
    for value in qs:
        value.total=total
        value.save()
    return qs

def generic_update_noreturn(__class__, pk, total)
    __class__.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('total')update(total=total)

def actualizar_cantidad(request, pk):
    ...
    total = calcular_nuevo_total(nce, pu)
    updated_cortadores=generic_update(Cortadores, pk, total)
    updated_otherexample=generic_update(OtherModelExample, total, pu)

    generic_update_noreturn(Cortadores, pk, total)
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer!. I needed to tweak my solution a little but you gave me the right idea. 


`qs_total = Cortadores.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('total')

s_total = calcular_nuevo_total(nce, pu)

qs_total.update(total=s_total)
`

this worked for me, as for using this method for multiple tools can you provide me a little more info  THANKS

Comment: Vinicius - Thanks ! Will try to implement it ASAP.